# App with wearable support not appearing in Play Store and all devices are not compatible

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, mobile-application

I just recently got my app approved and published on the Play Store but I can't seem to find the app in the Play Store no matter what I type. The direct link seems to work but it displays "This app is incompatible with your device" on every phone that I've tried. Is there something that went wrong?

My manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".FAQ2"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".FAQ" />
    <activity android:name=".Error" />
    <activity android:name=".MysteryPeakExpress" />
    <activity android:name=".MagicCarpet" />
    <activity android:name=".LodgeChair" />
    <activity android:name=".BrocktonChair" />
    <activity android:name=".MidwayChair" />
    <activity android:name=".SkyChair" />
    <activity android:name=".EasyRider" />
    <activity android:name=".RavenRidge" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LionsExpress"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_lions_express">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".EagleExpress" />
    <activity android:name=".Seymour" />
    <activity android:name=".Grouse" />
    <activity android:name=".Cypress" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="preloaded_fonts"
        android:resource="@array/preloaded_fonts" />
</application>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared that this is a wearable app and only runs on watches:

```xml
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

I assume from your question that you'd intended to create an app with wearable support, rather than an app that only runs on a watch.  To do this, you'd want to [add a wearable module to your app](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/creating#add-wear-os-module), rather than declaring that the main app uses `android.hardware.type.watch` (and remove this line from the main app's manifest).

If you didn't intend to add wearable support in the first place, then you can just remove that line entirely.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for the reply. I actually didn't intend on this being a wearable app at all, only a mobile app. Should I just get rid of that uses-feature line of code then? And is that the only line of code I need to get rid of?

Comment: Yep, there's no need for that line, as that feature would only be present on wearable devices.  I can't promise that there aren't any other issues I haven't spotted, but I think that should do it.